# jQuery-UI effect - double triggers event

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Trying to solve this one for a long time, jsfiddle wont re-produce this code to show the problem.

'click' event is getting triggered twice on the element, which was previously processed with hide() and show('slide').

Doesn't happen when using `show()` or `fadeIn(1000)`;
Doesn't happen when moving event handler inside `$(document).ready(){}`.

**I have to use this exact structure with `<script></script>` inside of the element.
No way I can change it.**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title></title>
<link href='/styles/jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<script src='/js/jquery.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
<script src='/js/jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#container').hide().delay(750).show('slide');
  });
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id='container'>
  <div class='download'>Download</div>
  <script type='text/javascript' id='js4container'>
    $('.download').click(function() {
      alert('Trigger');
    });
  </script>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I understand that `show()` does launch the inside of `<script></script>` once more, binding same event.

Is there a workaround? =)

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Specific engine. Loading part of code using AJAX. Cannot do anything about it. Plus - the structure is not an issue, there is definitely something going on with jquery-ui. Just hide() and show() should not cause any problems with events.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always use `.one()`, which only fires on the first event.  But you may still end up with multiple `.one()` triggers if you don't click between each call to `.one()`:

```
$('.download').one('click', function() {
     alert('Trigger');
});
```

Or, remove the handler(s) each time with `.off()`:

```
$('.download').off('click').on('click', function() {
     alert('Trigger');
});
```

This can also be written in the `delegate` syntax attached to `#container` or `body`:

```
$('body').off('click', '.download').on('click', '.download', function() {
     alert('Trigger');
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/QnfMZ/1/

**The reason this happens** is that jQuery UI uses helper elements to create transitions.  They maintain correct layout, etc while the animation is occuring.  These helper elements are created using `clone()` which copies the html of the element, which in your case means it copies the script, too.  The script then runs, adding a second handler.  After the transition is done, the helper clone is deleted, but you are still left with an extra handler.

Comment: P.S. I am curious what is actually causing the double-fire.  Simply showing and hiding the container doesn't seem to cause this behavior when I try to create the situation in jsfiddle.  Is something else actually causing this?

Comment: Nothing else. Just the code I provided. Copy paste and run - reproduces this exact problem. Wonder why regular show() or fadeIn - work just fine. I agree that hide and show are not related to any event handlers for the element. jQuery-UI bug?

Comment: Well, some transitions are created using clone helper elements.  When your element is cloned, it runs the script again, causing the handler to be attached again, even if the clone is deleted after the transition.  That is my guess anyway.  What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: Always latest. 1.7.2. If clone causes handler duplicate, then adding unbind() could solve the issue? Well - it does not. =))     $('#container').hide().delay(750).unbind().show('slide');

Comment: off('click').on('click') - works. Is this the only way to handle it? =))

Comment: @Radio, `unbind()` would work, but you need to call unbind on `.download`, not `#container`.  If you changed your click handler to this, your `unbind` line would work as you wrote it: `$('#container').on('click', '.download', function() { ... }`